# How to append data to a binary file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a binary file to which I want to append a chunk of data at the end of the file, how can I achieve this using C# and .net? Also is there anything to consider  when writing to the end of a binary file? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
private static void AppendData(string filename, int intData, string stringData, byte[] lotsOfData)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        bw.Write(intData);
        bw.Write(stringData);
        bw.Write(lotsOfData);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer because it shows you how to additionally shove native data types into the stream as binary representations.

Comment: @jdk - which of course makes a *lot* of presumptions about what the underlying data *is*; a `byte[]` sure, that would always make sense... but the encoding for the others could be *miles* out.

Comment: +1 for the binary writer, if you are writing binary data it is always best to use the writer

Comment: just wondering what would be the use case for appending binary data to the end of a file?Taking successive memory dumps maybe?

Comment: You might want to put your comment on the original question as the poster seemed to have a use case in mind.

Comment: My use case for this is I've got code that downloads large files in parts over multiple threads and I need to reassemble the parts into a single file. (The hosting server limits speed per connection, so multiple connections are my workaround to get the files faster.)

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do this via the `Stream`:

```
using (FileStream data = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
{
    data.Write(...);
}
```

As for considerations - the main one would be: does the underlying data format support append? Many don't, unless it is your own raw data, or text etc. A well-formed xml document doesn't support append (without considering the final end-element), for example. Nor will something like a Word document. Some do, however. So; is your data OK with this...

Answer (score 0):

Using `StreamWriter` and referencing [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter), make sure to add the `True` boolean to the `StreamWriter` constructor, if otherwise left blank, it'll overwrite as usual:

```
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // 1: Write single line to new file
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\log.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Important data line 1");
    }
    // 2: Append line to the file
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\log.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Line 2");
    }
    }
}

Output
    (File "log.txt" contains these lines.)

Important data line 1
Line 2
```

This is the solution that I was actually looking for when I got here from Google, although it wasn't a binary file though, hope it helps someone else.