# How can I go to the spacial line of data in binary file and read the only data in that line?

Tags: c#, arrays, binary

I would like to save data stored in an array in a binary file. As you see in the following code, my array has different value for each main iteration (t).

```
float[,] v = new float[3, 3];
string path = string.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"test.txt");

for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            v[i, j] = (float)Math.Sin(I * t + 10);
        }
    }

    FileStream ff = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

    using (StreamWriter ww = new StreamWriter(ff))
    {
        ww.Write("*" + t + "    ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                ww.Write(v[i, j] + ",");
            }
        }
        ww.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The question is: I would like to read the data in the file and store back in an array(2D). Code should go to the requested line ( in this example 0-2 ) and read data in that line and store them. I though it should be something like this.

```
> *0    -0.5411,-0.0211,-0.5211,-0.5411,-0.51,-0.541,-0.544,-0.0211,-0.5411,
> *1    -0.5411,-0.511,-0.5411,-0.992,-0.92,-0.902,-0.529,-0.5,-0.529,
> *2    -0.5411,-0.5211,-0.511,-0.529,-0.5729,-0.5329,0.974,0.974,0.994,
```

---

```
// go the second line and read data and store in the 2D array
string lineNo = "*1";
FileStream fff = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

using (BinaryReader www = new BinaryReader(fff))
{
    int index = www.IndexOf(lineNo); // this line does not work
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            v[i, j] = www.Read(1, index); // pass the line index and read data (doesn't work)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see if this link can answer your first question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398418/how-append-data-to-a-binary-file . you need to set FileMode.Append .

Comment: You should also add in `using` blocks to ensure the proper disposal of your `FileStream` objects.