# Append content of file to existing file

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I append the content of a file (any file extension) to an existing file with the same extension?
I have tried this

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(dest_path, System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fi));
```

but this works only for the .txt files

Comment: Does [File.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy) fit your needs?

Comment: I want to copy files of the directory so this is giving an error to copy the second file of the directory so it is not exact fit of my need

Comment: Marc Gravell's answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398418/how-to-append-data-to-a-binary-file) can give you a hint

Comment: whats your desired file extension in which you want to append content?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to concatenate a set of files together, like the DOS command `copy /b a.pdf + b.pdf both.pdf` - Reading all the bytes of N number of files and appending them all to a single file.

```
    using (var stream = new FileStream(pathOfFileToAppendTo, FileMode.Append))
    {
        foreach(var pathOfFileToAppend in ...) {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathOfFileToAppend);
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

If the files you want to append are very large, you might need a streaming approach instead of reading them all into memory with ReadAllBytes. The `...` is some array/list/enumerable of string filenames like you might get from `Directory.GetFiles` but it can be any set of filepaths.